# APC, PHP and two classes which require each other

Tags: php, opcode-cache

I'm managing an PHP application and we want to enable APC now. The problem is that we have two classes which require_once each other. A very basic example would look like:

```
in class_a.php

require_once('path/to/class_b.php)';

class a extends something {
    //
}

in class_b.php

require_once('path/to/class_a.php');

class b extends something2 {
    //    
}
```

However, when we enable APC, there is an "[apc-error] Cannot redeclare class class_b in class_b.php". Ok, that's because the class has been already loaded via the require_once() in class_a.php so if some 3th file requre class_b.php, APC will raise the error.

How to solve this "circular reference-like" issue?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have?  Make sure the paths are the exact SAME.  Make sure you do not have a lingering file with the same name somewhere in your include_path if you do not specify full path.

Comment: try to use autoloaders - this will prevent you to fallback in such kind of issues

Comment: PHP 5.3 and APC is the very latest version. All include path are absolute and exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this would be to get rid of the circular dependency itself. I thing it actually qualifies as *[Code Smell](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html)*.

Try following instructions in [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/). It should provide you with an alternative approach. I just hope that you can _*read*_ Java ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a "feature" that will allow you to override the `require_once` calls and allow them to be included multiple times. Since it appears you are using `require_once`, this appears to be your issue. To disable this check for the setting `apc.include_once_override` in php.ini or add in

```
[apc]
apc.include_once_override = 0
```

This setting has known issues with duplicate / not found classes etc. See if this helps